# If I Install Windows and Ubuntu in the same disc,Which one is better to instal first? Will I need anti virus in Ubuntu for Windows virus?

Tags: dual-boot

Is it better to install Ubuntu or Windows first? Will I need to install an anti virus in Ubuntu for Windows virus? If I install Windows first,Do I need to format Windows partition or Ubuntu takes part of the disc and formats in Ext4? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it good to install Windows after or before Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466418/is-it-good-to-install-windows-after-or-before-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I Install Windows and Ubuntu in the same disc...

I don't think you can have both in the same disc. They will most likely take up the whole DVD disc and some.

> Is it better to install Ubuntu or Windows first?

I believe installing Windows first is the way to go and then Ubuntu. Not sure about now but that was certainly the case back in 12.04.

> Will I need to install an anti virus in Ubuntu for Windows virus?

You don't need any antivirus in Linux (:

> If I install Windows first,Do I need to format Windows partition or Ubuntu takes part of the disc and formats in Ext4?

You don't format anything, Ubuntu at its installation will convert part of the disk space into ext4. If you have enough space left over, Ubuntu will just take as much space from Windows as it needs or you specify. So, when the partition finishes, Windows won't know about the partition Ubuntu resides in but interestingly from Ubuntu's side, you can access Windows files, which is an amazing experience if you are Windows centric person like I was.

Comment: Thanks! I asked the antivirus thing because I thought Windows virus could enter the sistem through Ubuntu and infect Windows.

Comment: Like i said, Windows don't have a permission or even the infrastructure to know Linux exist right beside itself. It's the Linux that will be able to access Windows with root privileges. On another note, you can have my answer marked as answered when it lets you, will appreciate (:

Comment: And unless you copy/paste the virus file from Ubuntu to Windows and from Windows side open it... I doubt it will affect you :P So, if you are trying to go that route, no anti virus in the world can save you ;)