# Is it good to install Windows after or before Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

Actually, I am using Ubuntu system and I want to install Windows. So which one is better? Installing Ubuntu before windows or windows before installing Ubuntu? Can you please clarify which method works?

Comment: In Non-UEFI machines, after installing Windows, you will have to run `grub2-install` so that you can boot into Ubuntu, or use `boot-repair`

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more? I didn't get many things which you said.

Comment: You need to install windows before Ubuntu, otherwise is likely that windows will nuke the bootloader. Apart of that, I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Why? I want Windows because I have to run software which doesn't work well with Ubuntu like MATLAB, to open word files, .ppt files and all which people use to send me.

Comment: Note that Matlab runs better on Linux than on Windows and has for some years.

Comment: @chrylis Link for downloading installing MATLAB in Ubuntu? I will be thankful to you. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [In setting up dual Boot with Windows and Ubuntu, which OS do I install first?](http://askubuntu.com/q/152991/301745)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is already pointed out, I just want to sum up everything:

When running a dual boot environment, a boot loader has to show you the operating systems installed and let you select which one you want to boot. The Ubuntu boot loader, GRUB, is capable of doing this, while the one of Windows is not.

Therefore, it is easier to first install Windows und Ubuntu afterwards. The Ubuntu installer will offer you to install Ubuntu beside Windows and will take care of everything. It's easy and the standard procedure.

Nevertheless, the other way round is possible, too. But the Windows bootloader will override GRUB. Because of that you'll have to reinstall GRUB. This can for example be achieved by booting a live system and running [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: One more thing, In which partition should I install Ubuntu? Can this be in same partition in which I have windows? Please explain  this.

Comment: You have to be sure to distinguish between [disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) and [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning). You can run Ubuntu and Windows on the same disk, but not on the same partition. When installing Windows first, the Ubuntu installer will automatically add two partitions to your disk: the root partition, where the system lies and a [SWAP partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq). If you have predefined (empty) partitions, or want something more special, you can select "something else" during the installation process.

Comment: and the partitions which Ubuntu will make(Two) will be part of which partitions? I mean I have windows and I have C,D,J. So in which drive will it make those two partions. Actually, I am not able to relate the Ubuntu and Windows thing.

Comment: By default, it will take the DRIVE Windows is installed on, shrink the Windows-PARTITION and add two other partitions. But if you want any other configuration, like installing on other DRIVES, you can use the "something else" option once you're asked by the installer. There, you will be able to partition everything just like you wish.

Comment: I think you might find [this well covered question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep both in dual boot you should install first Windows then Ubuntu because if you do it reverse Windows boot loader with erase Grub boot loader and then you need to reinstall to get access to Ubuntu.

Comment: what is grub? yes, I want to keep them both. I want system to ask me which OS I want to load now.

Comment: One may install in any order. If you install windows second, either configure the windows boot loader to boot Ubuntu or use boot-repair.

Comment: Yes, but as cioby23 pointed out, it is much simpler to install Ubuntu later. And Grub (Grand Unified Boot Loader) is the boot loader used in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First install Windows, then install Linux.

Linux installation could overwrite windows bootloader in MBR (or could leave it untouched if you wish so), and Linux bootloader could boot both windows and linux.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line, is that Windows is not known for "playing well with others."  Therefore, it is typically easier to install Windows first, and then Ubuntu (Linux).  This way, GRUB will search for (and find) your Windows partition, and list it as a boot option on your GRUB menu.

If you install Ubuntu first and then Windows, the Windows boot loader will replace GRUB.  Additionally, it will not look for other operating systems to boot into (by design, perhaps?).  Regardless of how you choose to solve that (adding Ubuntu to the Windows boot loader, or replacing it with GRUB) you will have additional work to do by installing Windows last.