# Re-installing OS's, best order?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, ssd

So I was going to take this weekend to throw in another SSD and install Ubunutu on it. But Windows (Win 7) has been acting up lately, so I was thinking I was going to go ahead and reinstall Windows while I was at it (I usually do this once a year-ish just to keep things clean). So what's the best order to do so?

Wipe and resinstall Windows SSD first, then throw in second SSD and install Ubuntu?

Throw in second SSD, install Ubunutu on it, then wipe and resintall Windows SSD?

Doesn't really matter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it good to install Windows after or before Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/466418/is-it-good-to-install-windows-after-or-before-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are installing on separate SSD's, it shouldn't really matter.

However, I HIGHLY recommend disconnecting the SSD (and all other hard drives) from your motherboard that you are NOT going to currently install anything on, it will drastically decrease your chances of error.

Answer (score 1):

Windows will try it's best to nuke grub if you install it after Ubuntu.

---

Install Ubuntu after Windows

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

A Windows OS should be installed first, because its bootloader is very particular and the installer tends to overwrite the entire hard drive, wiping out any data stored on it. If Windows isn't already installed, install it first. If you are able to partition the drive prior to installing Windows, leave space for Ubuntu during the initial partitioning process. Then you won't have to resize your NTFS partition to make room for Ubuntu later, saving a bit of time.

When a Windows installation already occupies the entire hard drive, its partition needs to be shrunk, creating free space for the Ubuntu partition. You can do this during the Ubuntu installation procedure, or you can see How to Resize Windows Partitions for other options.

If you have resized a Windows 7 or Vista partition and cannot boot up Windows, you can use the instructions from WindowsRecovery to fix it.

---