# Install Ubuntu and Windows to complete new laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I just got a brand new laptop which has FreeDOS in it right now. It has 128 GB of SSD and 1 TB HDD. I want to install Ubuntu root to SSD (and swap if required), Ubuntu home to 500 GB of HDD and Windows to other 500 GB of HDD.

I started with Ubuntu and tried simply creating partitions for ex4 for Ubuntu and NTFS for Windows. When I try to install Ubuntu to root partition, it gives the warning `NO EFI System Partition was Found`.

Any suggestions to how to do it? I tried to create fat32 partition before root partition to use it as efi boot partition, but couldn't make it.

I can give any additional information you need if you comment.

Comment: How you boot install media for both Windows & Ubuntu is then how it installs UEFI or BIOS. New systems are UEFI, so better to install in UEFI boot mode. Usually better to install Windows first, and if not to first drive see if you can turn off or hide SSD while installing Windows. It may modify partitions on SSD if SSD seen  as first drive. Ubuntu now uses swap file, no swap partition required. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it good to install Windows after or before Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466418/is-it-good-to-install-windows-after-or-before-ubuntu) and [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/)

Comment: @emremrah The Windows installer will format the boot drive for you; changing partitions with Ubuntu before installing Windows is counterproductive. Just install Windows then install Ubuntu with the option to put Ubuntu alongside Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I use both OS on my PC, and to do that, I first install Windows, and then Linux.
I create a partition for Windows and install it there
Then I boot from the Ubuntu flash drive and install it on the remaining hard drive space.